# Why are my icons not showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

This is a zip to the full project [QuickLinks.v4](http://www.mediafire.com/file/jkl8nt850jn70px/QuickLinks.v4.zip)

I have been collaborating on a project and we are stuck on an issue, we want all of the icon to have a right click menu that has several options that are unique to each icon. We are almost done but now the icons are not being drawn to the screen. We are only working on the first 5 at the time. This is my first time working with jQuery and I would appreciate any help.

I will now post pieces of the project that I think are relevant.

**icon.html**

```
<a target="_blank">
    <img class="icons" />
    <div class="data">
           <div>
                 <input type="hidden" class="login" />
                 <input type="hidden" class="username" />
                 <input type="hidden" class="password" />
           </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**icon.js**

```
function buildIcons() {
    var icons = [
        ["https://discordapp.com/", "discord-icon", "icons/discord.png", "social", "Discord", 
            [
                 ["Main Account", "lela_null", "somepass"], 
                 ["Bot Account", "Uta Yuki", "somepass"]
            ]
        ],
        ["https://www.youtube.com/", "youtube-icon", "icons/youtube.png", "social", "YouTube", 
            [
                 ["Main Account", "lela@email", "somepass"], 
            ]
        ],
        ["https://www.facebook.com/?sk=h_chr", "facebook-icon", "icons/facebook.png", "social", "Facebook", 
            [
                 ["Main Account", "lela@email", "somepass"], 
            ]
        ],
        ["https://www.twitter.com/", "twitter-icon", "icons/twitter.png", "social", "Twitter", 
            [
                 ["Main Account", "lela@email", "somepass"], 
            ]
        ],
        ["https://mg.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?.rand=8647i3s40jpvp", "ymail-icon", "icons/ymail.png", "social", "Yahoo Mail", 
            [
                 ["Main Account", "lela@email", "somepass"], 
            ]
        ]
    ];
  
    
    
    $.get('data/icon.html', function(data) {
        var icon;
        icons.forEach(function(iconData, index, array) {
            console.log(index);
            icon = $(data).insertAfter("#" + iconData[3]);
            $(icon).find("img").attr("src", iconData[2]);
        });
    });
};
```

**script.js**

```
/* get icon id */
function buildMenu(iconId) {
    $("#remove").click(function() {
       $("#" + iconId).hide();
       cancel();
    });
    $("#menu-title").text($("#"+iconId).data("name"));
    $("#site-link").attr("href", $("#" + iconId).parent().attr("href")).click(cancel);
    switch(iconId) {
    };
}

/* set right click for icons */
$(document).ready(function() {
    buildIcons();
    $(".icons").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
        buildMenu(this.id);
        $("#contextmenu").show().css({
            top: e.clientY,
            left: e.clientX
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function cancel() {
    $("#contextmenu").hide();
}
```

There is more files and code, if you may need, you may download it above.

Also the console says `TypeError: a is null` in my jQuery.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not have the ability to include html from another file.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
$.get('data/icon.html', function(data) {
    icons.forEach(function(iconData, index, array) {
        console.log(index);

        // Get 'data' as jQuery object
        var $data = $(data);

        // Find image tag and set source
        $data.find('img').attr('src', iconData[2]);

        //Finally put it on page
        $data.insertAfter("#" + iconData[3]);
    });
});
```

Comment: There is on noticeable difference in the outcome.

Comment: Your code is working as expected on [test setup](https://jsfiddle.net/28rgbm92/)  . Please ensure you getting expected HTML for get request to `data/icon.html`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to download the project and see if the troubled spot is different?

Comment: Send it... If possible setup JsFiddle.

Comment: It is [already working](http://imgur.com/a/wZAyq) , I guess you opening file by double clicking which opens in `file:///` , try to test in a web server. A NodeJs web server is easy to setup.

Comment: Check this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/ip8i5) showing icons not working and my guess it is same on your side. It is Chrome browser, press `ctrl+shift+I` to bring developer toolbar that shows error.  Waiting for your reply...